# Randomness vs Perceived Randomness

Tags: javascript

I've got a 'Random Content' button on my website, and it works, however, I want a more "perceived randomness" rather than true random.

I might not have the terminology correct, but what I want is that the same link isn't opened before 10 clicks from the user.

How would I implement this limitation? Currently this is my Code

```html
 <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Redirect From List</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
<div style="text-align:center;padding:15px;">
  <button style="text-align:center;" onclick="openLink()" type="button" name="" id="">Random Content</button>
</div>
<script>
var links = [
  "__LIST OF LINKS__"

];
function openLink() {
  var i = parseInt(Math.random() * links.length);
  window.open(links[i], '_blank');
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: (i) remove chosen item from list (ii) maintain a counter for each removed item (iii) increment counters for all items on openLink (iv) add back if the counter reaches 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Update: If you need no tracking across browser sessions, then the solution is Salman's comment is easier to implement and requires less effort.*

It depends on what is your intention behind this limitation.

If the users are not authenticated or you can allow users to bypass the limitation, you can simply use the browser's local store to keep track of the links clicked by the user.

If the users are authenticated, you have more options, but generally speaking you would want to keep track in some kind of database of which user clicked which link and how many times.

For the first case, you would need something like this, but make sure to have at least 10 links. (there are some rough edges in the code below)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Redirect From List</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <div style="text-align:center;padding:15px;">
        <button style="text-align:center;" onclick="openLink()" type="button" name="" id="">Random Content</button>
    </div>
    <script>
        const links = [
            "__LIST OF LINKS__"
        ];

        const storeItemName = 'linksClicked';
        var linksClicked = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem(storeItemName)) || [];

        function getRandomLink() {
            const i = parseInt(Math.random() * links.length);
            const link = links[i];

            console.log("length", linksClicked.length);

            /// Clear the list after 10 clicks
            if (linksClicked.length >= 10) {
                linksClicked = [];
            }

            if (linksClicked.includes(link)) {
                return getRandomLink();
            }

            return link;
        }

        function saveClick(link) {
            linksClicked.push(link);
            window.localStorage.setItem(storeItemName, JSON.stringify(linksClicked));
        }

        function openLink() {
            const link = getRandomLink()
            saveClick(link);
            window.open(link, '_blank');
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```